# Error while installing app in android emulator in win8

Tags: adb

As I was trying to install the app in my emulator through command prompt, it shows--
"error- more than one device and emulator."
I've 4 emulator but only 1 was online while I was installing the app.
I use this command (without quotes)
"adb install .apk"

Need help!!

Answer (score 0):

close emulator, close adb. open and reconnect, you can use

```
adb devices
```

to see connected devices.